# How should I organize my MongoDB database?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I'm pretty new to working with databases and I've been learning about the differences between NoSQL and MySQL. I'm building a web application that lets users create events to put in their calendar.

Right now, I have a collection for usernames and passwords, and a collection for each user that stores their events. But as I read more about NoSQL, it seems that instead I should have a collection for all events, and store each user's events in a single document. So I would just have 2 collections in my database, one for usernames and one for events. This seems to make more sense, but then I would end up with a very large events collection with large documents.

What is the best practice here? I've looked at a lot of MongoDB examples, but most only show simple databases with one collection.

Answer (score 0):

Effective modelling for MongoDB is not so obvious. There is rarely a definitive response, but I'll try to give you some hints.

A common principle with NoSQL databases is to model data according to the requests you are planning to make. If you need to get the list of all events, it's much more efficient to store all of them in a unique document. If you need to get the list of all documents for a given user, store it's event list in a document describing the user, and so on. This may lead you to duplicate some data: you could have both a list of all events and a list of event in each user document.

Then comes the usual dilemmna: should you embedd the complete event description in each document describing an user, on simply a reference to that event, which is stored in another document?

Once again it depends on the way you will make requests. If you have to update the events, it is preferable to embed only (part of) their immutable properties in the user document (at least an ID). If the events are immutable —and it's likely in this specific use case— you can embbed the whole event description in a user document. Or at least all the fields of the event description which are useful when you load an user.

Considering the size, limitations are described in [MongoDB's documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits).

Comment: I'm aware that the principle behind NoSQL is to have it be according to my requests, but I would have thought that the users collection would be an exception, esp. if i'm storing passwords, session cookies, etc

Comment: From my point of view it follows the general rules I described above.  Password and session data will need to be updated, so you'd better not duplicate them. ==> include them in the user document, and store the list of events (or just event ids) in this document too.